# Atomic Simulation Environment (ASE) Modelling. Adding additional layer

Tags: python, molecular-modeling, atomic-simulation-environment

Beginners here, to ASE. I've create a 2x2x2 supercell of TiO2 from unit cell (.cif file obtained from [LegacyMaterialsProject](https://legacy.materialsproject.org/materials/mp-2657/#) ) using ASE. The script code is attached as follows. The outcome is shown as part (A) of the picture. However, I want to include another additional one atomic layer into the 20Å vacuum slab. What can I do to improve the script code so that I can get the structure indicated as the image part (B)?

```
from ase import io
from ase.io import read, write
from ase.build.supercells import make_supercell
from ase.visualize import view

#Make supercell of 2x2x2
M = [[2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2]]
cif = io.read('TiO2_mp-2657_computed.cif')
sc=make_supercell(cif, M)

#Export supercell into vasp
write('supercell.vasp', sc, vasp5=True, sort=True, direct=False)

#Add vacuum of 20Å (10Å top-bottom)
vac = io.read('supercell.vasp')
vac.center(vacuum=10, axis=2)

#Export vac into vasp
write('supercell_20vac_test.vasp', vac, vasp5=True, sort=True, direct=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To build a 5 layer TiO2 surface slab, you need to first build a 2x2x3 supercell and then remove the top layer. To do this, you need to first identify the atom indices in layer 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (counting from bottom) using [`ase.geometry.get_layers`](https://databases.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/geometry.html#ase.geometry.get_layers), and then select only the atom indices that have the layer number smaller than 5.

You can use the code below

```
from ase import io
from ase.io import read, write
from ase.build.supercells import make_supercell
from ase.visualize import view
from ase.geometry import get_layers
import numpy as np

#Make supercell of 2x2x3
M = [[2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3]]
cif = io.read('TiO2_mp-2657_computed.cif')
sc=make_supercell(cif, M)
sc.center(vacuum=10, axis=2)
view(sc)

layers = get_layers(sc, (0, 0, 1), tolerance=0.3)[0]
indices = np.argwhere(layers<np.max(layers)).ravel()
new_sc = sc[indices]
new_sc.center(vacuum=10, axis=2)
view(new_sc)
```